# how to use parametrized cursor in another cursor using bulk collect and forall

Tags: oracle, plsql

The existed logic is taking data from CUST_MSTR table and inserting in customer_mac_feed using BULK COLLECT and FORALL.

Now the requirement in addition to the existed logic data needs to fetched from CUST_RELT table based on cust_gpid and cust_confid of CUST_MSTR table . i.e. c_cust_mstr cursor.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_parameterized_cur_bulk
    AS
    
    CURSOR c_cust_mstr IS
     SELECT  
     a.cust_modi_date,
     a.cust_id,
     a.cust_gpid,
     a.cust_confid,
     b.sch_id,
     b.sch_date,
     c.c_name
    FROM CUST_MSTR a,
    CUST_SCH b,
    CUST_REPO c
    WHERE a.cust_gpid=b.cust_gpid
    and b.B_flag=c.C_flag;
    
    p_cust_gpid VARCHAR2(8);
    p_cust_confid NUMBER;
    
    **CURSOR c_CUST_RELT(p_cust_gpid VARCHAR2,p_cust_confid NUMBER) IS
    SELECT relt_custid FROM CUST_RELT
    WHERE relt_cust_gpid=p_cust_gpid and relt_cust_confid=p_cust_confid;**
    
    TYPE v_cust_mstr IS TABLE OF c_cust_mstr%ROWTYPE;
    v_cust_mstr_TYPE v_cust_mstr;
    
    **TYPE v_cust_relt IS TABLE OF c_CUST_RELT%ROWTYPE;
    v_cust_relt_TYPE v_cust_relt;**
    
   
    
    BEGIN
     
     v_cust_mstr_TYPE :=v_cust_mstr();
     v_cust_relt_TYPE :=v_cust_relt();
      
     OPEN c_cust_mstr;
     LOOP
      FETCH c_cust_mstr bulk collect INTO v_cust_mstr_TYPE limit p_cccnt;
      V_RECORDCNT :=V_RECORDCNT + v_cust_mstr_TYPE.COUNT;
      BEGIN
      FORALL REC IN 1..v_cust_mstr_TYPE.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
      INSERT
      INTO customer_mac_feed
      (
      MODIDATE,
      cust_id,
      gpid,
      CONFIGID,
      schid,
      schdate,
      cname
      )
      VALUES
      (
      v_cust_mstr_TYPE(REC).cust_modi_date,
      v_cust_mstr_TYPE(REC).cust_id,
      v_cust_mstr_TYPE(REC).cust_gpid,
      v_cust_mstr_TYPE(REC).cust_confid,
      v_cust_mstr_TYPE(REC).sch_id,
      v_cust_mstr_TYPE(REC).sch_date,
      v_cust_mstr_TYPE(REC).c_name  
      );
      COMMIT;
      
     **OPEN c_CUST_RELT(v_cust_mstr_TYPE(REC).cust_gpid,v_cust_mstr_TYPE(REC).cust_confid);
     LOOP
     FETCH c_CUST_RELT bulk collect INTO v_cust_relt_TYPE limit 100;
     FORALL i IN 1..v_cust_relt_TYPE.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
     INSERT
       INTO customer_mac_feed
      (
      MODIDATE,
      cust_id,
      gpid,
      CONFIGID,
      schid,
      schdate,
      cname
      )
      VALUES
      (
      v_cust_mstr_TYPE(REC).cust_modi_date,
      v_cust_relt_TYPE(i).relt_custid,
      v_cust_mstr_TYPE(REC).cust_gpid,
      v_cust_mstr_TYPE(REC).cust_confid,
      v_cust_mstr_TYPE(REC).sch_id,
      v_cust_mstr_TYPE(REC).sch_date,
      v_cust_mstr_TYPE(REC).c_name  
      );
      
     EXIT WHEN c_CUST_RELT%NOTFOUND;
     END LOOP;
     CLOSE c_CUST_RELT;**
     EXIT WHEN c_cust_mstr%NOTFOUND;
     END LOOP;
     CLOSE c_cust_mstr;
     
     EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
     RAISE;
     END;
    END proc_parameterized_cur_bulk;


Now the requirement in addition to the existed logic data needs to fetched from CUST_RELT table based on cust_gpid and cust_confid of CUST_MSTR table.
If data is existed for these two combination of columns in CUST_RELT table then take only cust_id from CUST_RELT table
and take remaining columns from CUST_MSTR table and insert in CUSTOMER_MAC_FEED table.

Source Tables:
CREATE TABLE CUST_MSTR
(                                                                                            
cust_gpid VARCHAR2(10),
cust_confid NUMBER, 
cust_id VARCHAR2(10),                                                                                                                                                                                                                       cust_modi_date DATE,
cust_account varchar2(11) 
); 
                                                                                            
CREATE TABLE CUST_SCH
(
cust_gpid VARCHAR2(10),
sch_id NUMBER,
sch_date DATE,
B_flag VARCHAR2(1)
);

CREATE TABLE CUST_REPO
(
c_name VARCHAR2(20),
C_flag VARCHAR2(1)
);

CREATE TABLE CUST_RELT
(                                                                                            
relt_cust_gpid  VARCHAR2(10),                                                                                             
relt_cust_confid NUMBER,                                                                                          
relt_custid    VARCHAR2(10),                                                                                          
relt_ownername  VARCHAR2(20),                                                                                          
relt_ownerloc VARCHAR2(10)                                                                                          
);

Target Table:
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_MAC_FEED
(                                                                                            
modidate DATE,
cust_id VARCHAR2(10),
gpid VARCHAR2(10),
configid NUMBER,
schid NUMBER,
schdate DATE,
cname VARCHAR2(20)
);

Insert Statements:
                                                                                      
INSERT INTO CUST_MSTR VALUES('AP1122',572072,'A1',TO_DATE('12-MAR-2021','DD-MON-YYYY'),334455671);
INSERT INTO CUST_MSTR VALUES('AP1122',571010,'B1',TO_DATE('18-MAR-2021','DD-MON-YYYY'),334455672);
INSERT INTO CUST_MSTR VALUES('AP1122',674521,'B1',TO_DATE('15-MAR-2021','DD-MON-YYYY'),334455673);
INSERT INTO CUST_MSTR VALUES('AP1122',457534,'C1',TO_DATE('01-MAR-2021','DD-MON-YYYY'),334455674);
INSERT INTO CUST_MSTR VALUES('ST5577',271956,'C1',TO_DATE('14-MAR-2021','DD-MON-YYYY'),334455860);
INSERT INTO CUST_MSTR VALUES('ST5577',271957,'B1',TO_DATE('08-MAR-2021','DD-MON-YYYY'),334455861);
INSERT INTO CUST_MSTR VALUES('KK6688',234981,'A1',TO_DATE('11-MAR-2021','DD-MON-YYYY'),334455771);
INSERT INTO CUST_MSTR VALUES('MR7700',360787,'C1',TO_DATE('10-MAR-2021','DD-MON-YYYY'),334455571);

INSERT INTO CUST_SCH VALUES('AP1122',111,TO_DATE('12-FEB-2021','DD-MON-YYYY'),'Y');
INSERT INTO CUST_SCH VALUES('ST5577',222,TO_DATE('14-FEB-2021','DD-MON-YYYY'),'Y');
INSERT INTO CUST_SCH VALUES('KK6688',444,TO_DATE('11-FEB-2021','DD-MON-YYYY'),'Y');
INSERT INTO CUST_SCH VALUES('MR7700',888,TO_DATE('10-FEB-2021','DD-MON-YYYY'),'Y');

INSERT INTO CUST_REPO VALUES('C_COMMON','Y');

INSERT INTO CUST_RELT VALUES('AP1122',457534,'B2','ALEN','USA');
INSERT INTO CUST_RELT VALUES('ST5577',271956,'C2','KHAN','UK');
INSERT INTO CUST_RELT VALUES('ST5577',271957,'C2','BEN','USA');
INSERT INTO CUST_RELT VALUES('KK6688',437692,'B2','JACK','AUS');
INSERT INTO CUST_RELT VALUES('MR7700',360787,'B2','MUSK','AUS');

Expected output in the target table CUSTOMER_MAC_FEED as below.
Note : Showing only few columns 

AP1122  572072  A1  12-MAR-2021
AP1122  571010  B1  18-MAR-2021
AP1122  674521  B1  15-MAR-2021
AP1122  457534  C1  01-MAR-2021
AP1122  457534  B2  01-MAR-2021
ST5577  271956  C1  14-MAR-2021
ST5577  271957  B1  08-MAR-2021
ST5577  271956  C2  14-MAR-2021
ST5577  271957  C2  08-MAR-2021
KK6688  234981  A1  11-MAR-2021
MR7700  360787  C1  10-MAR-2021
MR7700  360787  B2  10-MAR-2021
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe a simplified example with sample data demonstrating the technical issue you are facing would make it easier to propose a solution.

Comment: OK, I think I can see what you are trying to do. You want the inner loop to run for each row fetched by the outer loop, but as the outer loop bulk-collects those rows into a collection *n* rows at a time, you can't easily access the `cust_gpid` and `cust_confid` values you need for the inner loop.

Comment: Yes. And one column value from inner cursor and remaining columns values from outer query. The code which is highlighted in bold I added to the existed logic. Please help me.

Comment: I edited my post with DDLs and insert statements.

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure has several issues, some minor but a couple quite serious. In the section below I break the procedure and where there are issues.

```
create or replace procedure proc_parameterized_cur_bulk as

    cursor c_cust_mstr is
       select  
          a.cust_modi_date, 
          a.cust_id 
       from cust_mstr a 
       join cust_sch  b on a.cust_gpid=b.cust_gpid 
       join cust_repo c on b.b_flag=c.c_flag;  
   
    p_cust_gpid varchar2(8);    
    p_cust_confid number;

    cursor c_cust_relt(p_cust_gpid varchar2,p_cust_confid number) is
      select relt_custid from cust_relt
      where relt_cust_gpid=p_cust_gpid and relt_cust_confid=p_cust_confid;
```

Minor Issue. The above variables,  p_cust_gpid and p_cust_confid,  are  unnecessary. The names are the same as those in the in the cursor following then. But they are *not the same variable* as they are in a different scope. Formal cursor parameters defined are local to the that cursor. According to [cursor scoping rules](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/cursor_declaration.htm):

> The scope of cursor parameters is **local to the cursor**, meaning that
> they can be referenced only within the query used in the cursor
> declaration. The values of cursor parameters are used by the
> associated query when the cursor is opened.
> (Emphasis mine)

Since formal cursor variable override the other declaration they are not used else where the are not needed.  
IMHO: Parameters do not have to be p_ that is just a convension. My convention, cursor parameters are indicated as c_. Staying with p_ is not incorrect I just find c_ more descriptive.  Continuing:

```
type v_cust_mstr is table of c_cust_mstr%rowtype; --<IMHO keep type definition based on cursor close to cursor.  
    v_cust_mstr_type v_cust_mstr;
    
    type v_cust_relt is table of c_cust_relt%rowtype; --<IMHO keep type definition based on cursor close to cursor. 
    v_cust_relt_type v_cust_relt;
 
begin    
     v_cust_mstr_type :=v_cust_mstr();
     v_cust_relt_type :=v_cust_relt();  

     open c_cust_mstr;
     loop  --- outer loop
     
        fetch c_cust_mstr bulk collect into v_cust_mstr_type limit p_cccnt; --<<< p_cccnt undefined
        v_recordcnt :=v_recordcnt + v_cust_mstr_type.count;  
        --<<< what's the point? v_recordcnt is undefined and not used elsewhere 
        
        begin  -- inner block      
        
           forall rec in 1..v_cust_mstr_type.count save exceptions  
              insert
                 into customer_mac_feed
                 (
                   modidate,
                   cust_id
                 )
                 values
                 (
                    v_cust_mstr_type(rec).cust_modi_date,
                    v_cust_mstr_type(rec).cust_id 
                 );
            commit;
```

**DO NOT COMMIT** here.  
You are in the middle of your transaction. What happens when an error occurs later in the code. How do you restart/recover? Further in this you does not commit anywhere. BASIC rule to follow: 1 commit at conclusion of procedure, and only 1 commit.  There are time this needs to be set aside, but it should be the rare exception as a last resort. And make sure restart/recover process is well documented.  Continuing:

```
   open c_cust_relt(v_cust_mstr_type(rec).cust_gpid,v_cust_mstr_type(rec).cust_confid);
```

Invalid reference to REC. It is only defined as the index variable of the forall. According to the [forall scoping rules](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/forall_statement.htm#LNPLS01321)

> Name for the implicitly declared integer variable that is local to the
> FORALL statement. Statements outside the FORALL statement cannot
> reference index. Statements inside the FORALL statement can reference
> index as an index variable, but cannot use it in expressions or change
> its value. After the FORALL statement runs, index is undefined.
> Containing:

```
           loop
              fetch c_cust_relt bulk collect into v_cust_relt_type limit 100;
              forall i in 1..v_cust_relt_type.count save exceptions           
                 insert
                   into customer_mac_feed
                      (
                       modidate,
                       cust_id
                      )
                   values
                      (
                        v_cust_mstr_type(rec).cust_modi_date,
                        v_cust_relt_type(i).relt_custid
                      );
                
           exit when c_cust_relt%notfound;
           end loop;        
            
         close c_cust_relt;
         exit when c_cust_mstr%notfound;
```

Your control  (following) flow completely breaks down at this point.
You have an outer loop and inside that loop an inner block (begin) However, you attempt to close (end loop) that loop before closing the block. You must either close the inner block first or remove it.  
Your exception, as it stands is useless. The only thing it accomplishes is distort the line number that an error actually occurred. It will report the line number of of RAISE. Making finding the problem more difficult. Perhaps this is just a simplification gone wrong.  
Further more you use "forall ... save exceptions" twice, but never attempt to do anything with any exceptions saved.
Continuing:

```
     end loop;  -- outer loop
     close c_cust_mstr;          
     exception
         when others then
         raise;
        end;  --inner block 
end proc_parameterized_cur_bulk;
```

I have put together a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=95b0a39388ac03ed70664a4487eb604a) showing 3 versions.

1. This is what I believe is a corrected version but essentially
   maintaining the format of your orig. I did add labels to indicate
   code start/end segments. Labels are never required but sometimes
   very useful.
2. This is a consolidation and simplification of the first. By JOINing
   the cust_relt table you can get the relt_custid in the mast_cust
   cursor. Then use forall twice using the same collection. No iterating
   the collection and selecting each time through just to get 1 column
   of additional data.
3. Finally, if your error rate is low, a version that consists of just 2
   insert statements - that all. However it is 1 error and out.